# How to remove the orphaned SPD Workflow Instance using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, powershell, designer-workflow

How to clean-up or remove the orphaned workflows in a  site collection?

I have created a SPD 2010 reusable workflow and deployed in SP 2013 environment. But for some of the sub sites and some document libraries I am unable to trigger this workflow.

So I want to delete the existing workflow instance which is associated with the content types from this site collection.

Is there any PowerShell script to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://weburl
$list = $web.Lists["Document Library"]

$ct = $list.ContentTypes["ContentTypeName"]

foreach($association in $ct.WorkflowAssociations)
{
    write-host $association.name

    $ct.RemoveWorkflowAssociation($association)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But its not completely removed from my site, though its not seen  when I check in the workflow settings of my document library. But I am able to see the "deleted"  workflow instances when I went through the SP D and clicked  on the content types, and in the workflows section. It has become the orphaned workflow instance now.

Comment: Try closing and reopening SPD